# Issue with Google docs JavaScript code (API)

Tags: javascript, google-docs

I have been developing a google docs extension with JavaScript code.

Below is the code.

```
// Constants
const API_KEY = "MmGPTAPI";
const MODEL_TYPE = "gpt-3.5-turbo"; //chatGPT model

// Creates a custom menu in Google Docs
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu("ChatGPT")
      .addItem("Get Quick Anchor", "generateAnchor")
      .addToUi();
}

// Generates prompt based on the whole document content and adds it to the document
// Generates prompt based on the whole document content and displays it in a sidebar
function generateAnchor() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const text = body.getText(); // Get the entire text from the document

  const prompt = "Find anchor text related to this document content: " + text;
  const temperature = 0;
  const maxTokens = 50;

  const requestBody = {
    model: MODEL_TYPE,
    messages: [{ role: "user", content: prompt }],
    temperature,
    max_tokens: maxTokens,
  };

  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + API_KEY,
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", requestOptions);
  const responseText = response.getContentText();
  const json = JSON.parse(responseText);
  const generatedText = json['choices'][0]['message']['content'];

  // Split the generated text into paragraphs
  const generatedTextArray = generatedText.split('\n');

  // Create an HTML list with bullet points
  let htmlContent = '<ul>';
  for (let i = 0; i < generatedTextArray.length; i++) {
    htmlContent += '<li>' + generatedTextArray[i] + '</li>';
  }
  htmlContent += '</ul>';

  // Create a custom sidebar
  const htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(htmlContent)
    .setTitle('Generated Text')
    .setWidth(300);
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput);
}


// Creates a custom menu in Google Docs
function onOpennn() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu("Links")
      .addItem("Get link", "searchGeneratedTextInCustomSearch")
      .addToUi();
}

// Function to search generated text in a custom search engine
function searchGeneratedTextInCustomSearch(generatedText) {

  // Replace 'YOUR_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID' and 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your actual search engine ID and API key.
  const searchEngineId = 'Engine_ID';
  const apiKey = 'MY_API';

  // Define the search query using the generated text
  const searchQuery = "q=" + encodeURIComponent(generatedText);

  // Send a request to your custom search engine using the Search Engine ID and API key
  const searchUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" + apiKey + "&cx=" + searchEngineId + "&" + searchQuery;

  // Add 'num' parameter to specify the number of results (maximum 10)
  const numResults = 10;
  const searchUrlWithNum = searchUrl + "&num=" + numResults;

  const searchResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(searchUrlWithNum);
  const searchResult = JSON.parse(searchResponse);

  // Parse the search results to extract SERP links
  const serpLinks = searchResult.items;

   // Format the SERP links
  let serpLinksHtml = '<ul>';
  for (let i = 0; i < serpLinks.length; i++) {
    const link = serpLinks[i].link;
    const title = serpLinks[i].title;
    serpLinksHtml += '<li><a href="' + link + '">' + title + '</a></li>';
  }
  serpLinksHtml += '</ul';

  // Create a custom sidebar to display the SERP links
  const htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(serpLinksHtml)
    .setTitle('SERP Results')
    .setWidth(300);
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput);
}
```

One function from this code will help me to extract anchor text from the content in google docs. This will appear in the docs sidebar. For this I have integrated GPT API and prompt. The another function will help me to search that anchor text in the google custom search engine. I have integrated search engine ID and API for this. After searching anchor text in search engine, I want this function to show 10 SERP title and links results in the sidebar.

There are two menu created. One menu is for anchor text and another menu is to get links. Both menu works without  error. when I click on get quick anchor menu I get anchor text in sidebar and when I click on get link menu I get links in sidebar. but here's some issues:

1. The links I get in sidebar are very irrelevant. It looks like the function is not searching anchor text in the custom search engine. Example: If anchor text is "hello world" then the function is not able to search "hello world" in search engine and not able to give me links relevant to "hello world".

Both functions has separate menu, is that causing the issue?

Please help me with this code as I am very beginner in JS. I built this code by referring to some videos and GPT. But I am unable to solve this.

What I want?

1. I want function to search anchor text as query on search engine and not any other text.
2. I want "when I click on get link menu, the results link should be in sidebar with 10 SERP results title and link results. Example: If function search anchor text "hello world" in the custom search engine then the 10 SERP results should be in sidebar "hello world."